# Javafx Tableview scrolling right by pressing right arrow key

Tags: javafx, tableview

I have a tableview which contains 30 columns, because of the total width exceed the width of the tableview, so the tableview shows the first 7 columns first, so I need to move to the right by pressing right arrow key on the keyboard, in the first 7 columns, when I press right arrow key, the focus will move to the next column as expected, when it reaches the 8th column, the 8th column will become the first one to show on the table view, so far so good, but the question is, when I press again the right arrow key trying to move to the next column(9th,10th...), instead of focus moving to the next column, all the columns will shift left with one column, that makes me very difficult to see the content of the column.

So I would like to ask if there is any setting of the tableview for moving the focus only if pressing right arrow key on the keyboard instead of shifting all the columns left in the table view?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no setting for this behavior as fer as i know.

Calling `TableView::scrollToColumn` and `TableView::scrollToColumnIndex` appears be have same behaviors. We should add `EventHandler` for `KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED` fired by right and left keys to change this movement.

Comment: Hello @monolith52, Thanks for the reply, based on what you mentioned in the answer:"We should add EventHandler for KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED fired by right and left keys to change this movement.", Can this movement be solved by add this EventHandle?could you explain more with details?

Comment: 1. Handle KeyCode.RIGHT and KeyCode.LEFT. 2. Select and focus adjacent cell. 3. compute and set position of TableView's ScrollBar. I wrote [test handler](https://gist.github.com/monolith52/9bb81966461ebcaf2e4044e610c8f821) when I answered you. Try this if you'd like.

Comment: Hello @monolith52, Thanks you very much:), It is great, and almost there, but there is a problem, for example, the tableview can show 7 column at one time, when I press right key to the 8th column, I would like the 8th column to become the first column position in the table view, now the case is 8th column is in the last position of the tableview. Could you do a little modification? Thanks again!

Comment: @Kevin Xu, Sorry, I wrote the code to check just changing behavior. To make the code fit for your case, it will be [like this](https://gist.github.com/monolith52/614b7eddb7ef4a56bd9ee15da3fd0ec9).

Comment: Hello @monolith52,That code works great and fantastic! Thank you very much!,  I would add a little request, Could ENTER key works like the right arrow key? so when I press the ENTER key, it will behave the same like the RIGHT arrow key.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Kevin Xu. Please challenge it by yourself, it should not be difficult. At least, it's getting off topic of your question. Good day!